# Bcrypt's compare is not working in Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, bcrypt

I was following the tutorial from Dev.to. But I stucked on this: bcrypt's compare not working
The code:

```
const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if (!isMatch){
    return res.status(400).json({
      msg: "incorrect password"
    });
  }
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#with-promises, If its still not working kindly check console logging the password, user.password values.

Comment: It's unclear what are you looking for. An explanation? Are you getting an error and need help fixing it? Please provide debugging details to help us help you

Answer (score 0):

Is the string coming from `user.password` a hash?

bcrypt compares your raw string with a hash. Here's a simple working example that you can run in a node file.

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const bcryptTest = async () => {
  try {
    const password = 'mypassword';
    const userPass = await bcrypt.hash('mypassword', 5);
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, userPass);
    console.log(isMatch) // returns true
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

bcryptTest();
```

Comment: So while saving the hashed password in the database, we have to save the salt too right?

Comment: Well, bcrypt handles that for you. It generates the salt and incorporates it into the hash. There are methods that let you generate the salt manually and use it in the hash function, but that's redundant, as in the example above the salt is automatically generated over 5 "rounds".

Answer (score 0):

Be careful; the second parameter of 'compare' is a hashed password, usually obtained from the database.
-> bcrypt.compare(passwordLogin, hashedPassword)